# Proving an identity involving pushforward

Tags: differential-geometry, complex-geometry, projective-space, pushforward

Let
$$\pi \; : \; \mathbb{C}^{n+1} \backslash \{ 0 \} \longrightarrow \mathbb{P}^n \; : \; (z^0, \ldots z^n ) \longmapsto (z^0 : \cdots : z^n )$$
be the map onto **homogeneous coordinates** of the complex **projective space** $\mathbb{P}^n$. Denote by $\pi_{\ast}$ the **push-forward** of $\pi$ to the corresponding tangent spaces and denote the **pullback** by $\pi^{\ast}$.

---

Within my lecture on complex manifolds, my professor stated that

$$ \pi_{\ast} \sum_{i = 0}^n z^i \frac{\partial}{\partial z^i} \enspace = \enspace 0 $$

However, he did not prove it, he just vaguely outlined an idea for a proof by stating that when computing

$$ \pi^{\ast} \; d \bigg( \frac{z^i}{z^0} \bigg)$$

then

$$\pi_{\ast} \frac{\partial}{\partial z^i}$$

should somehow follow.

I am interested in how this proof is carried out in more detail, because I don't see where his outlined idea is going.

---

**EDIT 1:**

Thank you for your answers so far. I think I understood the approaches in the comments . However, I am also interested in the way my professor is suggesting. If I am not mistaken, the following equations hold:

$$ \pi_{\ast} \bigg( \sum_{i = 0}^n z^i \frac{\partial}{\partial z^i} \bigg) (f) \enspace = \enspace \sum_{i = 0}^n z^i \, \pi_{\ast} \bigg( \frac{\partial}{\partial z^i} \bigg) (f) \enspace = \enspace \sum_{i = 0}^n z^i \frac{\partial}{\partial z^i} \, ( \pi^{\ast} f ) $$

where $f$ is an arbitrary function. How do I proceed and where do I need $\pi^{\ast} d \big( \tfrac{z^i}{z^0} \big)$? Did I already go astray?

Comment: It seems to me that it's easy enough to prove this directly using the basics. The definition of the pushforward of $\pi_*v$ is that it is $(\pi\circ c)'(0)$, where $c(t)$ is a curve such that $c'(0) = v$. Here, $v = z^i\partial_i$, so you can set $c(t) = (1+t)(z^0, \dots, z^n)$. But $\pi\circ c(t) = (z^0: \dots : z^n)$ is constant, so $\pi_*(z^i\partial_i) = (\pi\circ c)'(0) = 0$.

Comment: In fact, the pushforward of $\pi_{\ast}$ at $(z^0,\dots,z^n)$ is surjective and its kernel is precisely generated by the tangent vector with coordinates $(z^0,\dots,z^n)$  (surjectivity can either be calculated in coordinates or by noting that $\mathbb{P}^n$ is a quotient). This should not be surprising geometrically: all that $\pi$ does is collapse lines to points, so the tangential directions it kills should be precisely the radial ones (all in a complex sense). This is precisely the point of Deanes calculation as well.

Comment: Thank you for your answers, I updated the question (see **EDIT 1**).

Comment: You need to be more precise about much of what you've written. What does it mean to say "... stating that when computing...then $$\pi_*\frac{\partial}{\partial z^i$$? That's not a complete sentence. Presumably, you meant to write a full equation in the display? Second, the sequence of equations in the display cannot hold, because $\pi_*(\dots)$ is in the tangent space of $\mathbb{P}^n$, but in the subsequent equations, $z^i$ is not well defined as a function on $\mathbb{P}^n$. It might be clearer to you and us, what's going on, if you try to write down things more carefully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The functions $u^i: \mathbb{P}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$, given by
$$u_i(z^0:\cdots:z^n) = \frac{z^i}{z^0},\ 1 \le i \le n,
$$
are well-defined. Moreover, their differentials $du^1, \dots, du^n$ are a basis of $T_{(z^0:\cdots:z^n)}^*\mathbb{P}^n$. Using this fact, you can show that to prove
$$
\pi_*\left(\sum_{j=0}^n z^j\frac{\partial}{\partial z^j}\right) = 0,
$$
it suffices to show that, for each $1 \le i \le n$,
$$
\left\langle\sum_{j=0}^n z^j\frac{\partial}{\partial z^j},\pi^* du^i\right\rangle = 0\text{ on }\mathbb{C}^{n+1}\backslash\{0\}.
$$
This is now a straightforward calculation.

Comment: I very much understood your explanation and consequently the proof that was hinted at by the professor. I appreciate your help - thank you!